# Pass variable to attributes in ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post, ejs

I want to pass the `board[i]` value in the ejs to the server, here is my code:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="list">
      <% for (var j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) { %>
      <li> <%= board[i][j] %> </li>
      <% } %>
      <form class="" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" value="">
        <button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <% } %>
```

I tried to use javascript code like setting `board[i]` to the attribute like the value tag so that I can obtain it, but I don't think that works since nothing happened when I added `console.log` in the script. Any ideas about how can I do this?

Comment: did you get any error and at what point were console login?

Comment: In my terminal, there is nothing occurred, so I suspect the script doesn't execute? I put my script inside the <form>.

Comment: did you now see the data on your console after placing it in the form and how are you passing data

Comment: No, nothing is printed. I passed the data using the post request by the form.

Comment: can you show a demonstration( your code) of post request, please?

Comment: The form has an attribute `method="post"`, so I think it will post the request when I click the button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209649/discussion-between-akolliy-and-hui-yu).